# How can I allow a wordpress user to view, add, update or delete specific custom posts via the admin?

Tags: wordpress, access-control

Once this user is created by an admin role.

My goal is to give this wordpress user only access to his/her posts -  can view, add , update or delete in Wordpress admin.

My goal is to create a wordpress user that can view, add , update or delete in Wordpress admin.

I DO NOT want to use plugins

I want the user to be able to access only the ids it creates in multiple custom post types. say user x is setup, he can only work with his posts (ids) in custom post types (say: businesses, products, orders)

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually do this, but you may be better off just using a Role Editor plugin like [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/). The alternatives would be to give the [Roles & Capabilities](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/) documentation a read, and decide if it's better to modify an existing role, or creating a new role and give it the select permissions you want.

For instance, you'd probably want to create a new role based on the `editor` role, and remove all of the `{blank}_others_{blank}` capabilities, such as [`edit_others_posts`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#edit_others_posts), [`delete_others_posts`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#delete_others_posts), etc.

If you do go the programatic way instead of plugin, note that the Roles & Capabilities are stored in the database, so you don't need to include the function that creates/modifies them on every load like the [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) hook. If you do put it on a hook like that, you'll probably want to set a flag of some sort (like with [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/)) and abort if the new role/cap hasn't been changed since it was last run.

Comment: Hi Xhynk , no plugins. I want the user to be able to access only the ids it creates in multiple custom post types. say user x is setup, he can only work with his posts (ids) in custom post types (say: businesses, products, orders)

Comment: Then you'll need to follow the second and third paragraphs I wrote. Create a new role based on the `author` or `editor` role, and remove the `..._others_...` caps, add the `create_` and `publish_` caps, and make sure your Custom Post Types have `map_meta_cap` enabled.

Comment: No. Each user would be a "name-of-your-new-role". if you base it off of the existing `author` role, that role will need publish/delete capabilities added to it. If you base it off the existing `editor` role, you'll need to remove the `edit_others_{…}` capabilities from it. Either method will let that any user with that role edit/publish their own things, and not others.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to do this using the Author role.

https://en.support.wordpress.com/user-roles/

Author
An Author can create, edit, publish, and delete only their own posts, as well as upload files and images. Authors do not have access to create, modify, or delete pages, nor can they modify posts by other users. Authors can edit comments made on their posts.

Within a CPT set the capability type to post.

'capability_type' => 'post'

Comment: Hi Mark, I want the user to be able to access only the ids it creates in multiple custom post types. say user x is setup, he can only work with his posts (ids) in custom post types (say: businesses, products, orders)

Comment: Helps if I read it all sorry about that.

Set the capability type to post within your CPT this still uses the native WP capabilities.

Updated my answer to reflect this.